# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char[]'

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have the following code but giving an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'char[]'"

```
char[] hTempFile = new char[300 + 1];
hTempFile ="";
```

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with the `hTempFile="";` line?

Answer (score 5):

A `char[]` is different to a `string`. If you intend to be an empty array, then:

```
hTempFile = new char[0];
```

or perhaps simply (if you add a few null-checks):

```
hTempFile = null;
```

There is also `.ToCharArray()` on a `string`, but that seems overkill here.

Frankly, for a file-name, it *sounds* like you should *actually* be using `string` here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a C style string initialization, in C# it is best to avoid using char arrays for strings and use the string class instead.

```
string hTempFile = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.ToCharArray()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) to get array of char from string....If the string is empty like in your given example, the returned array is empty and has zero length....

```
hTempFile = "".ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? you have already defined hTempFile as type char[].

You cannot assign a string value to hTempFile .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set hTempFile to an empty string -- or, more specifically, the C-string representation of an empty string. If that's the case, all you need to do is

```
hTempFile[0] = 0;
```

Since C-strings are null-terminated, placing a null byte in the first char of the array effectively empties the string.